# ffmpeg video encoding has no audio

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, video, video-conversion, encoding

When I convert any video in ffmpeg - e.g. mp4 to mkv, mkv to mkv - I lose audio for some reason
here are the parameters I originally used:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf scale=640x480 -vcodec libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -preset medium -crf 23 -x264-params ref=4 -acodec libvorbis -movflags +faststart output.mkv`

I tried mkv to mkv with the same paramaters and then I deleted most of the things to get this:
`ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf scale=640x480 output.mkv`

there is still no audio even when simplifying this much
can somebody help please

Comment: MKV is a package format, and the audio and video inside it can vary widely. I would guess that this may be a factor in what you're dealing with. Do you know what format the audio in this MKV file is supposed to be in? Also, what research have you done regarding this prior to asking here?

Comment: Your output audio codec is `vorbis`, which is an old and not much used codec. Switch to `-acodec aac` and check.

Comment: How should I check what format the audio is in my original mkv files?, I will try -acodec aac thank you for the help

Answer (score 0):

Think you need to tell ffmpeg to copy the audio, try:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mkv -vf scale=640x480  -c:v libx264 -profile:v main -level 3.1 -preset medium -crf 23 -x264-params ref=4 -c:a libopus -movflags +faststart output.mkv
```

And maybe try adding `-map 0:v:0 -map 0:a:0`

At least thats what I use at it works